# Running a shell script on remote servers and passing a command line argument to it

Tags: shell, ssh

I want to run top command through a script on remote servers.
I also want to add a filter that will allow only integers to pass as a command line argument to the script which will run on the remote servers

this is the command which i'm using:-

```
ssh -oConnectTimeout=5 -oBatchMode=yes -l group servername 'bash -s' < /some/path/top_command.sh
```

Now when i'm not passing any argument to the script, it works fine and displays top 20 lines of the `top` command.

it is also filtering out the garbage values like any character (non integer)

But the issue is with the negative integers

```
ssh -oConnectTimeout=5 -oBatchMode=yes -l group servername 'bash -s' < /some/path/top_command.sh -7
```

Now i'm getting an error:-

```
Usage:  bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
    bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
    --debug
    --debugger
    --dump-po-strings
    --dump-strings
    --help
    --init-file
    --login
    --noediting
    --noprofile
    --norc
    --posix
    --protected
    --rcfile
    --restricted
    --verbose
    --version
    --wordexp
Shell options:
    -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option          (invocation only)
    -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option
```

But when i try running the command like without using the top_command.sh script:-

```
ssh -oConnectTimeout=5 -oBatchMode=yes -l group servername 'top -b -n 1 | head -n -2'
```

I'm getting the `top` command's output for negative `head` values

Now i'm confused, what am i doing wrong?

**Btw Content of top_command.sh**

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
  3         echo -e "No Argument passed:- Showing default top 20 lines\n"
  4         command=$(top -b -n 1 | head -n 20 2>&1)
  5         echo "$command"
  6 else
  7         re='^[-0-9]+$'
  8         if [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then
  9                 command=$(top -b -n 1 | head -n $1 2>&1)
 10                 echo "$command"
 11         else
 12                 echo "Argument passed is not an integer"
 13         fi
 14 fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like

```
ssh -oConnectTimeout=5 -oBatchMode=yes -l group servername bash -s -- -7 < /some/path/top_command.sh
```

`--` is a common option-argument separator that is helpful when passing arguments starting with `-` to a command. Commands like `mv` and `rm` also recognizes it. Everything that follows `--` is no longer tested as being an option or not and is already just considered as a normal argument. To `rm` and `mv` it's helpful if the file starts with `-`.

Comment: will it also work if i do `ssh` from a linux machine to solaris?

Comment: @Disturbed_Entity Not sure as I don't have solaris. However it might be likely if you're using similar ssh versions (the ssh server there that is), and that bash is also available there.